# Find out the number of CPU cores used by a linux job

Tags: linux, cpu-cores

How can I find out how many CPU cores is a job running on a Linux system using?
Is it somehow through the `top` command?

Comment: This isn't foolproof, but you often know for a fact that a process is using more than one core when its usage exceeds 100% CPU. Same for 2 cores and 200%, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ps -aF` or I am guessing you are referring to [`htop`](http://hisham.hm/htop/) which is a graphical tool.

Comment: for top usage: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command